# (Bootstrap) Collapsable navbar button looks wrong and not in correct area?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a button that collapses/shows the navbar when the screen is smaller than a certain size. Not only is the button not showing correctly(it only shows 1 horizontal bar instead of 3) its also not positioned correctly, as I would like it to be on the far right of the screen, similar to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ if you resize the browser. What it currently looks like :http://prntscr.com/5zif5q

Navbar Code:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <!-- Button for navbar when using small screen -->
          <button type="button" class"navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">

            <!-- The horizontal lines of the navbar button for small screens -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#fighters" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Fighters<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#F7F-Tigercat">F7F-Tigercat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#F8F-Bearcat">F8F-Bearcat</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#bombers" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Bombers<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#B-17-Flying-Fortress">B-17 Flying Fortress</a></li>
                <li><a href="#B-52-Stratofortress">B-52 Stratofortress</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#drones" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Drones<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#MQ-1-Predator">MQ-1 Predator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#MQ-9-Reaper">MQ-9 Reaper</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, I could not find the error. Here's my pen `[http://www.bootply.com/V92ijl6cch][1]

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
```